# How to properly call a class while providing error reporting at the class-caller level

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

I am writing *fresh* code, as part of refactoring an older legacy codebase.

Specifically, I am writing a `Device` class that will be used to compute various specifications of a device.

`Device` class depends on device's model number and particle count and I can call it as `$device = new Device($modelNumber, $particleCount);`

Problem:  since this class will go into existing legacy code, I have no direct influence on if this class will be called properly.  For `Device` to work, it needs to have correct model number and correct particle count.  If it does not receive the proper configuration data, internally device will not be initialized, and the class will not work.  I *think* that I need to find a way to let the caller know that there was an error, in case an invalid configuration data was supplied.  How do I structure this to be in line with object oriented principles?

Or, alternatively, do I need to concern myself with this?   I think there is a principle that if you supply garbage, you get garbage back, aka my class only needs to work properly with proper data.  If improper data is supplied, it can bake a cake instead, or do nothing (and possibly fail silently).  Well, I am not sure if this principle will be great.  I do need something to complain if supplied configuration data is bad.

Here is some code of what I am thinking:

```php
$device = new Device($x, $y); 
$device->getData();
```

The above will fail or produce bad or no data if $x or $y are outside of device specs.  I don't know how to handle this failure.  I also want to assume that $device is valid when I call getData() method, and I can't make that assumption.

or

```php
$device = new Device($x, $y); 
if ($device->isValid())
    $device->getData();
else
    blow_up("invalid device configuration supplied");
```

The above is better, but the caller has to now they are to call isValid() function.  This also "waters down" my class.  It has to do two things:  1) create device,  2) verify device configuration is valid.

I can create a `DeviceChecker` class that deals with configuration vefication.  And maybe that's a solution.  It bothers me a little that DeviceChecker will have to contain some part of the logic that is already in `Device` class.

Questions

- what problem am I trying to solve here?  Am I actually trying to design an error handling system in addition to my "simple class" issue?  I think I probably am...  Well, I don't have the luxury of doing this at the moment (legacy code base is huge).  Is there anything I can do now that is perhaps localized to the pieces of code I touch?  That something is what I am looking for with this question.

Comment: First of all, how is the Device class going to be called within the legay codebase? Does your Device configuration parameters result in different set of behaviours for the Device object ?

Comment: I'd call it `$device = new Device($x, $y);`.  Different parameters do not result in different behaviors at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think you need to use below code to verify your passed arguments in construct
```

```
  class Device {
        public function __constructor($modelNumber, $particleCount) {
            if(!$this->isValid($modelNumber, $particleCount) {
                return false; //or return any error 
            }
        }
    }
```

```
This will check the passed params are valid or not and create object based on that only, otherwise return false or any error.
```

Comment: cool. .. I like it.  But what do you think of using `Exception` constructs instead of returning false?

Comment: Yes, sure you can use Exception by using try/catch in your calling of device class and throw exception from device constructor instead of returning false, and you can display that error to user from catch block.

Comment: accept because of the Exception comment makes a fuller answer